# Declined Flag Dispute

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

I recently flagged an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19121186/916299) with the reason:

> Duplicate answer of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17803738/916299

but the flag was declined.

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

It may not have been clear from the flag, but the answer was posted twice *on the same question*. Is this really not something I should flag?

[image]

Comment: You should have used other and explained the same user posted the same answer twice. That looks like you're saying the question is a duplicate (if you don't follow the link and just read quickly)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Fat fingered that one, but in the future, **include more information**. We see a lot of "this is a duplicate answer" flags that are completely meaningless. Here's a better flag:

> Duplicate of answer on same question from same user.

This conveys that the user has posted two of the same answer *on the same question*, which is much more actionable and gets our attention better.

Comment: But if I (or someone) provide a link to the duplicates in flags, shouldn't they be checked as well?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Honestly, no. I don't always follow the link. A *lot* of these flags are pointless and get declined. So unless you give me some better reason to investigate further, you're not going to achieve much with the flag.

Comment: -1 for making mistakes robo-moderators shouldn't be doing

Comment: +1 for fat-fingering... whoops, meant -1